# Display channel entry by date and limit to upcoming only

Tags: channel-entries, date

Unsure how to get this... I need to display from a gigantic list of events, sorted by start-date but only displaying 1 event that is set to happen the soonest but not already ended.

```
{if entry_date >= current_time}
    {title}
{/if}
```

The above shouldn't work because the limit applies before the loop. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `start_on` parameter within the channel entries tag. Something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="channel_name"
    limit="1"
    sort="asc"
    start_on="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'}"
    show_future_entries="yes"
}
```

Comment: switching from desc to asc and that worked like a charm!

Comment: Awesome, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the free Solspace add-on called [Date Field Filter](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/date_field_filter/). It would allow you to dynamically set a start date of current_time which would then be future-friendly in the way you're looking for.

Comment: The difference between this one and the answer above is that this one would allow you to use a custom field for your start and end date, and not have to use your publish date (which I prefer to maintain separately for publishing control). Date Field Filter allows you to map a custom field to the usual date behaviour of the entries loop without using the publish date. Just a matter of what suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using the start_on and stop_on has flexibility without using an add-on. Add a bit of PHP to increase your options.
I frequently want to display just entries that are dated either in the next and/or last 7 days.
You need to allow PHP on input in the template. Change the 604800 to however many seconds you want the time period to be.

```
<?php
$start_time = $this->EE->localize->format_date('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i', $this->EE->localize->now - 604800);
?>
<?php
$stop_time = $this->EE->localize->format_date('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i', $this->EE->localize->now + 604800);
?>

{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" show_future_entries="yes" dynamic="no" start_on="<?php echo $start_time; ?>" stop_before="<?php echo $stop_time; ?>" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc"}
```